# I think someone cloned A. Patterson in Tiny Tower

Tags: tiny-tower

I have two people named A. Patterson living in my tower, but it would seem they're listed as one person. The bitizen count in the corner also seems to think they're one person, and they can't be  separated. They're always listed in the same slot (apartments, jobs, etc.) and they have the workload of one bitizen. They wear the same clothes (they can both walk around) and as much as I'm sure this is just a glitch in the way bitizens are organized, I'd like it to be fixed.

Comment: Do you think you could attach a picture?

Comment: I had that problem too. I'm pretty sure the bitizen in question went away after restarting the game.